# Angular 7 elements problem with ng-start-inserted

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, styles

Hello I have the following template

```
<div>
      <span *ngFor="let sentence of obj.text; let i = index;">
            <ng-container *ngIf="1==1">
                  {{sentence}}
                  <input matInput (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" id="box_{{i}}" value="{{box[i]}}" />
            </ng-container>
      </span>
</div>
```

This template is correctly displayed when I open the url directly in the browser, however, if I open the template using router navigate the elements are not displayed inline. 
Also, when I compare the code I notice that angular is inserting "ng-star-inserted" style class.
In addition, the input is not displayed.
Is there any way to remove the ng-star-inserted or to force the displaying of the elements inline?

Comment: What do you mean by 'open the url directly'? Do you have this set to a route and open that?

Comment: Also, the `ng-start-inserted` should not have much to do with the issue, unless you are using animations.

Comment: For example, if I use a link with the route "/myexample", it is not going to work. But if I put the url (http://localhost:4200/myexample) directly in the browser, the template is displayed correctly.